# wowjs animate css not working wowjs not adding animated class to html element

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, wow.js

if you go here    [site here](https://assimilating-detent.000webhostapp.com/)    and  check with developer tools you will see this line

```
<!--Single portfolio item one-->
<section class="single-items center-block parallax m-0" id="home" style="background: url(innovative/img/single-portfolio1.jpg)">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12 center-col">
                <div class="area-heading text-center wow fadeInUp" data-wow-delay="0.8s">
                    <h3 class="area-title text-capitalize alt-font text-white mb-2 font-weight-100 ">
                        Nuestro <strong>loren ipsun</strong>loren ipsun</h3>
                    <p class="text-white font-weight-300"> loren ipsun</p>
                    <a href="#creative" class="btn btn-transparent-white btn-rounded btn-rounded btn-large mt-3 scroll">loren ipsun</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</section>
```

lacks the  * animated * class, tried :
manually setting animated css, bootstrap css,  and animated js, wow js , did not work....
stripped down all the css and js and just left basic html with animate css and js and wow js, nothing happened

what could be happening ? , this template have bootstrap and animate css in one bundle js css file

wasted between 2, 4 hours debugging console and found not the culprit of this error

What i am trying is:

to enable the wow animate js css effect like this site  [site here](https://industriasradisol.com)

if you check with developer tools this last site you will see that will be adding animated class to wow fadein class.. however that is not happening in the first one... and do not know why!

what could be causing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me that you forgot to initiate the `wow.js` as told in the [documentation](https://wowjs.uk/docs.html), so you just need to add the initiation code to it. And a quick fix would be to add:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    new WOW().init();
</script>
```

Below `<!-- custom script -->` line in your code (or anywhere before `</body>` tag).